# what is enc={someBase64String} in URL's?

Tags: asp.net, url

I've noticed on some ASP.net sites that some of their URLs have the following tacked onto some of their internal URLs:

```
somePage.aspx?enc=looks_like_a_base_64_encoded_string_here=
```

Any idea what purpose it serves?  I've tried passing it through a base-64 decoder, but it's nothing human-readable.  Looks like it's usually 64 bytes though.

Just wondering!

Comment: it's just a query string parameter to the page and it could be interpreted however.

Comment: Thanks Bala.  I know that it's a query string param, but there seems to be consistent use of the "enc=" for the parameter name, and base-64 for the value, so I was wondering if ASP.net used it for something special internally (like maintaining some sort of state or something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine it is a set of query string parameters; Googling around for examples of this behavior, I stumbled on [this blog post](http://madskristensen.net/post/HttpModule-for-query-string-encryption.aspx) that talks about encrypting your query string parameters.

Comment: Answers should be self contained so if an external resource disappears the answer is still valid. Links should be there to support a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special in .net for a query string parameter named "enc".

Most likely a number of dev's are just using the same mechanism for encoding querystring parameters.

Who knows, maybe someone started calling this the "Encoded Query String Pattern" ;)